# Eigen matrix multiplication slower than cblas?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, eigen, blas

I use the following code to test Eigen perfomance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#define EIGEN_NO_DEBUG
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <cblas.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
    int n = 3000;

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1, t2;

    Eigen::MatrixXd A(n, n), B(n, n), C(n, n);

    t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    C = A * B;
    t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto dur = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1);
    cout << "eigen: " << dur.count() << endl;

    t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cblas_dgemm(CblasColMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans,
                n, n, n, 1.0, A.data(), n, B.data(), n, 1.0, C.data(), n);
    t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    dur = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1);
    cout << "cblas: " << dur.count() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with the following command:

```
g++ test.cpp  -O3 -fopenmp -lblas -std=c++11 -o test
```

The results are:

eigen: 1422 ms

cblas: 432 ms

Am i doing something wrong? According to their benchmark it should be faster.

Another problem is that using numpy i get 24 ms

```
import time 
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((3000, 3000))
b = np.random.random((3000, 3000))
start = time.time()
c = a * b
print("time: ", time.time() - start)
```

Comment: What version of Eigen and g++ are you using?

Comment: With numpy arrays, `*` is *element-wise* multiplication.  Change `c = a * b` to `c = a.dot(b)`.  Or, if you are using a sufficiently new version of Python 3 and numpy, you can write `c = a @ b`.

Comment: Avi Ginsburg, Eigen version 3.2, g++ version 4.9.2, the problem was in using Eigen 3.2

Comment: Warren Weckesse, sorry about a*b i decided to test it just before asking the question, and forgot about a.dot(b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying that you are using `cblas` provide very little information because `cblas` is just an API. The underlying BLAS library could be netlib's BLAS, OpenBLAS, ATLAS, Intel MKL, Apple's Accelerate, or even EigenBlas... Given your measurements, it is pretty obvious that your underlying BLAS is an highly optimized one exploiting AVX+FMA+multi-threading. So for fair comparison, you must also enable those feature on Eigen's side by compiling with `-march=native -fopenmp` and make sure you are using Eigen 3.3. Then the performance should be about the same.

Regarding numpy,  Warren Weckesser already solved the issue. You could have figured out yourself that 24ms to perform `2*3000^3=54e9` floating point operations on a standard computer is impossible.

Comment: thank you, the problem was in using Eigen 3.2. I switched to Eigen 3.3 now it is 500 against 350. I dont know what blas library i was using, i installed package libblas3 and libblas-dev. Here is what apt-cache search says: libblas3 - Basic Linear Algebra Reference implementations, shared library, libblas-dev - Basic Linear Algebra Subroutines 3, static library

Comment: With Eigen 3.2 compiling with -march=native didn't change anything, but if i compile without that option using Eigen 3.3 it runs much slower